# Пожарный извещатель

Tags: delphi

Есть приборы пожарной сигнализации, работающие по беспроводному принципу на радиоканале. 
А именно пожарный извещатель (который на потолке) ручной пож.извещатель (который на стенке и срабатывает от механического воздействия на него) и говорилка, которая обеспечивает грамотную эвакуацию. Все эти устройства, так же по радиоканалу соединены с радиорасширителем (он производит все анализы и выдает дальнейшие команды др.устройствам, т.е является главным), который в свою очередь соединен с компом по RS-232.

Имеется протокол обмена данными всей этой системы. Ну и самое интересное...

Задача - создать простой интерфейс для охранника-бородача и соединить эти приборы с программным обеспечением написанным на delphi. Т.е при срабатывании одного из извещателей (ручной или кот.на потолке) программа выдавала окно сообщения, с вариантами действия (например, включить пожаротушение или наоборот отключить тревожный сигнал).

Возможно ли реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: Мне кажется, проблема не связана с языком программирования. Окошко с сообщением можно выдать практически во всех языках. Вопрос состоит только в том, можно ли и при помощи чего управлять всеми устройствами, которые Вы перечислили.

Comment: Это, как раз очень интересно, возможно ли с помощью Delphi, отвечать на действия датчиков, производить простое управление?

Comment: Если проблема и будет, то не в delphi, а в виндах. Лет десять назад мне говорили, что у виндов по скорости реакции при работе с com-портами могут быть проблемы. Правда винды тогда были другими.

Comment: Вот, кажется, примеры по вашей теме: http://z-oleg.com/delphi/hardw5.htm

Answer (score 3):

С com портом очень легко работать, и скорость работы тут ни при чем. Oхранник будет дольше думать что нажимать. Достаточно быстро реализуется алгоритм же простой

1. пришел сигнал о пожаре
2. выдается окно о выборе действия
3. выбирается действие охранником и посылается сигнал по всё тому же com порту.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли будет, вставить схемы плана здания созданные в microsoft visio, в создаваемый интерфейс в Delphi?

Comment: Я думаю, что в этом случае проще будет экспортировать чертеж визио в png или pdf формат, и потом его уже подгружать. Но если необходимо имеено работа с visio, то копать необходимо в сторону ActiveX TDrawingControl.

Answer (score 2):

Писал когда-то на C++Builder'е (тот же Delphi) приложение, которое через COM-порт связывалось с электронным табло для отображения субтитров в театре.

Вся сложность в Вашей задаче только в том, чтобы найти библиотеку для работы с конкретным портом. Ссылка, которую привел [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd) в комментарии к вопросу, например, показывает, как работать с портами напрямую. Уверен, существует масса компонентов-обёрток + документация.

Протокол вы реализуете. Имея опыт в Delphi, быстро реализуете UI.

Всё остальное - вопрос упорства. Удачи!

Comment: Компоненты-обёртки? Нафига... Но вот это повеселило:

      Вся сложность в Вашей задаче только в том, чтобы найти библиотеку для работы с конкретным портом.

Да, найти библиотеку для работы с com1: действительно непросто. И, главное, не перепутать её с библиотекой для com2:

Comment: Главное, с USB не перепутать :)

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли будет, вставить схемы плана здания созданные в microsoft visio, в создаваемый интерфейс в Delphi?

Comment: Вероятно, под библиотекой подразумевался какой-то интерфейс, позволяющий прикрутить, скажем, событие для отлавливания поступления данных. Наголо же, вроде, это нужно самому реализовывать: одно дело —  как-то кустарно (по таймеру), а можно же как-то по-умному — с аппаратной частью работать (не знаю как).